# Help with Sudo installation commands?

Tags: sudo, playonlinux, wget

How do I use these commands?

> For the Trusty version
>
> Type the following commands:
>
> ```
> wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo  apt-key add -
> sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install playonlinux
> ```

Comment: I forgot to tell you guys that I run ubuntu 16.04.1 Mate 64 bit

Comment: first of all: these commands are for *trusty* (14.04.x) - you are running *xenial* (16.04.x). when you found the commands for your mate 16.04 xenial, you start a terminal (open the apps menu and click on `terminal`) and copy and paste them directly into the command line presented by the terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Open a terminal** by either searching it on Dash
   <kbd>Super</kbd> and type `terminal`; or open it with the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
2. **Type the commands**, *one by one* (each line is a single command), manually on the `terminal` or copy them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and paste them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after every command.
4. When asked for your **`sudo` password**, type it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, note that your password wont appear on screen, thats for obvious security measures.